# How to delete specific document from SOLR admin console

Tags: java, solr

I tried to delete specific document from SOLR admin console with the following approach and query executed successfully but document could not deleted.

1. Go to the admin console.
2. Go to the document page.
3. Selected /update handler.
4. Selected document type as XML
5. Commit true
6. Commit within 1000
7. query:  `<delete><query>source_type:xyz</query></delete>`

[image]

**Note:**

1. In this image source_type:xyz not showing but we tried with `<delete><query>source_type:xyz</query></delete>`query.
2. `source_type` is one of the field in our schema.

We will really appreciate if some one can help us on this.

Answer (score 1):

I found the way for the same double quotes worked for me.

`<delete><query>source_type:"xyz"</query></delete>`

Comment: I would have thought that you need to use "Solr Command" (instead of "XML") as the Document Type for this to work, at least that's what the documentation says under the XML type: "This option will only add or overwrite documents to the index; for other update tasks, see the Solr Command option."